# Expected hitting times of continuous time Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a continuous time Markov chain with Q-matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -3 & 2 & 0 & 0 &1\\
    0 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & -5 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and corresponding jump chain matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 &\frac{1}{3}\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I work out the expected time to hit 4 starting from 1?

I've tried conditioning on the first step, but the first step can potentially get stuck in a loop which never hits 4 so the law of total probability for expectations results in an infinite time to hit 4.

Comment: Well then, you have proved the expected time is infinite.

Comment: If I am reading the matrices correctly, if $J$ is the number of jumps required to get from 1 to 4, you get: $$ J = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}2 & \mbox{ with prob 1/3}\\ \infty &\mbox{with prob 2/3}\end{array}\right. $$ and so we also have $E[J]=\infty$.